# PPA for vim builds with python, ruby etc interfaces enabled?

Tags: ppa, vim

Title says it all... looking for a vim ppa which is recent builds (within last week) of vim with language bindings enabled...

I found this: https://launchpad.net/~dgadomski/+archive/vim-daily but lua,  ruby  and python 3.3 isn't enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This repo has daily vim builds with python, ruby and lua enabled:

https://launchpad.net/~dgadomski/+archive/vim-daily

Comment: This PPA is now no longer maintained.